# htaccess: the server responded with a status of 500

Tags: jquery, ajax, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

**Original code working in localhost:**

```
var form_data = {
                    'email':$('#inviteEmail').val(),
              };

    $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo site_url('invites/save_email') ?>",
            type: 'POST',
            data: form_data,
            success: function(msg) {
                window.location.href = "<?php echo site_url('invites/moreinvites')?>"
                return true;
            }
    });
```

It works fine on localhost and CSRF is turned off. But when I moved it to media temple hosting, I started getting `500 Internal server error`.

**Server Error Log**

> Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable
>   configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the
>   limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

My htaccess file has this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /thesavv/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

I have no idea about this error.

Comment: Do you have access to view the server error logs?

Comment: I had this error before and was pulling my hair out. Turned out a problem in my controller/method

Comment: What was the error? My controller is working fine on localhost.

Comment: hosting configuration error ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error using my hosting: What worked well on local, did show a 500 error on production server.

It's a typical error, Joomla instalations have the same when deleting index.php from the url, and the problem is due to your htaccess file, if you change the Rewrite rule you wrote to avoid the index.php in the URL, it should work. Just delete the question mark:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L] **TO** RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]`

and probably it'll work. I think I remember that is due to the kind of URI PROTOCOL is using CI (you can see this in application/config/config.php, line 33), but not totally sure, maybe someone can explain it better, :P